# htaccess file to redirect all but root page to other domain (good idea or not?)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have the following issue:

- I have a website running on website.com
- It has nice PageRank and many incoming links, however the website is in Dutch and we get more and more international clients.
- Therefor, I want to bring this website to another domain (website.be) and install a new website on website.com in English, focussing only on our international oriented products

My idea is to have a htaccess file to redirect all traffic to the website.be domain (where I copy/paste the exact website). However, the root of the domain website.com should obviously not be redirected.

Is this a good idea (looing at Google value) and if so, how should this htaccess file look like?

Answer (score 0):

This could be looked at as duplicate content (copy/paste exact website). I would suggest creating subdomains. Check out the Google article on it: 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html

Comment: But if I redirect in 301, there won't be double content right? I will have different content on the .com domain.